# why text showing late with font-face?

Tags: css

I've used font-face for some of my headings but When I am refreshing my page content font appears as it load but font-face heading taking time to render on page. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: are you loading your font-face from a relative folder in your site or from an external link?

Comment: what is your browser ?

Comment: all font are in relative folder and I am facing this in almost every browser.

Comment: Can we see it in action ?

Comment: Wow ok, it's a huge latency ! I'll inpect this a bit

Comment: Ok you have 404 with all of your font files

Comment: It might be two things. First, you have a typo in your filename (in your normalize.css), or you just forgot to upload the files to your server or you did it in the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While inspecting your website, you have obvious errors :

```
GET http://mydomain.com/themes/woodlandsdentistry/fonts/FranklinGothic-Book.woff 404 (Not Found)
```

and same with `.ttf`, `.woff` and `.eot`

Now, looking at your code, you have another font that works just great. So my guess is you didn't upload the font files (or you did it in the wrong place) or the filename of your fonts have a typo an then doesn't match.

In my case (I use google chrome), the browser is looking at the `.woff` file and only get a 404 from the server after 4 seconds (same thing with other missing font files). So yeah, this is your delay.

Use your console next time !